# Can a Dependent Sample T-Test be Used on Sample Group (A) of 100 Electrical Devices, Tested at time, t1, shuffled, and Tested at time, t1?

Tags: t-test, predictor, independence, dependent-variable

**Description**:

I have a group of 100 electrical parts being testing for Forward Voltage, at time, t_1. This is my sample group, S1.

This same group is undergoing a stress test that may or may not affect the Forward Voltage. This would be my intervention. The only thing is, these parts will be shuffled around and washed during the intervention.

S1 will then be tested again at time, t_2.

Unfortunately, there will be no way to associate, say, part 1 of S1, to the same part in S1 after the shuffle, meaning that I might be comparing it to part 48 of S1, but the members of the sample group don't change.

Technically, all the parts are related in that they are supposed to all behave identically in electrical property.

I understand (or hope I do), that a Dependent Sample T-Test requires the ability to link measurements in a meaningful way at the individual level, which since these are technically all identical, may work for this application test model.

My goal would be to use this as a way to justify that the Null is not statistically significant; no change will be introduced by this stress test.

**Question**:

Can I use the Dependent Sample T-Test in this situation or do I have to resort to an Independent Sample T-Test? (I ask because I keep seeing that the Independent is for when you have a different sample made of different variables like people, items, etc.)

Thank you.